# PHP's ftp_fput failing to upload data to a remote server

Tags: php, ftp

I have been trying to send JSON encoded data to my remote server for storage, but I have not been able to get it to work. I am hoping to send the JSON data to an existing file on my server and append it to the end of the file.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
$jsondata = json_encode($record);

$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp://MY-USERNAME:MY-PASSWORD@MY-REMOTE-ADDRESS");
$temphandle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($temphandle, $jsondata);
rewind($temphandle);

if(ftp_fput($conn_id, 'test.txt', $temphandle, FTP_ASCII)){
    echo "Successfully uploaded data";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading data";
};

ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($temphandle);
```

My if statement must be returning fail because I am getting the problem error. I believe my FTP connection is successful. I have tried to put this together by studying many samples and I am unsure as to where my problem is. I am thinking one of the parameters for my `ftp_fput` function is incorrect. I greatly appreciate any help in getting this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you ftp connection is good? I see no test for that.

Comment: Hi, I was just assuming that it was a good connection because if I input the FTP information into my browser, I can see my directory no problem. I realize it is not good to assume and I will try and implement a test to make sure the connection is established. I am just learning as I go, thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you don't have to be using ftp. You should be using sftp. Your user name and password are sent over plain text. Also if you are going through a firewall there are some other annoyances.

Comment: "*getting the problem error*": What does that mean? Do you mean that you get the "There was a problem while uploading data"? If the `ftp_fput` fails it issues at least a warning. What is that? Make sure you have [warnings enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Answer (score 0):

*You didn't really provide us any information that can be used to identify the problem.*

Anyway, you are using the active FTP mode. The active FTP mode hardly works these days due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs. In general, you should always use the passive mode.

For details, see my article on [FTP active and passive modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

In PHP, you switch to the passive mode by calling the [`ftp_pasv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php) after the `ftp_connect` (or the `ftp_login`, if you use that).

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("ftp://MY-USERNAME:MY-PASSWORD@MY-REMOTE-ADDRESS");
// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
```